# Find many objects CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, orm

I have on my CakePHP project some Categories that hasMany Subcategories that hasMany Texts that hasMany and belongToMany tags.
To rephrase it, the Texts can be tagged and belong to a subcategory. A subcategory belong to a category.

I'm looking for a clean and efficient way to get these informations out of the table. I want for all Categories, all of these Subcategories, the Texts that depends on it and their tags.

I think in the first time that my controller should return an array like :

```
['categories'=>[[
    'name'=>'cat1' 'subcategories'=>[[
        'name'='sub1', texts=>[[
            'name'=>'text1', 'tags'=>['tag1', 'tag2']
        ]]
    ]]
]]]
```

So i tried to build this structure by hand and I made a loop in a loop in a loop... The code was so horrible I knew my way was wrong.

I tried to join all the tables together with the 'find' method but it doesn't seem to work.
here is the beginning of the code :

```
        $query = $categories->find('all', [
        'where'=>['Categorie.enabled ='=>true],
        'join'=>[
        [
            'table' => 'Subcategories',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'Subcategories.categorie_id = Categories.id'

        ],[
            'table' => 'Texts',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'Texts.subcategorie_id = Subcategories.id'

        ]
        ],
        'fields' => ['Subcategories.name', 'Categories.name']
        ]);
```

I got two row, one for each subcategory but I can't see the texts.

Am I doing right using joins ?
Why the texts I created are not visible on my test page ?
Is my orthographic mistake on the singular of categories the reason of this malfunction ?

I hope I'm understandable.

Comment: `$categories->find()->contain('Subcategories.Texts.Tags');` done. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations**